# How do I use Ajax to auto refresh a div across domains?

Tags: php, ajax, json, refresh

Can someone help me out? I have an html file that calls a php script via ajax and displays a random number that the php script generates. It works just fine when both files are on the same domain, but if the 2 files are located at different domains, which is what I need, nothing happens. Can someone help me fix this.

The code for the HTML file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug.  without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
setInterval(function() {
$('#divToRefresh').load('http://www.OTHERDOMAIN.com/random.php');
}, 5000); // the "5000" here refers to the time to refresh the div.  it is in milliseconds. 
});
// ]]></script>
 </head>
 <body>
<div id="divToRefresh">Loading users...</div>  
 </body>
</html>
```

If the line

```
$('#divToRefresh').load('http://www.OTHERDOMAIN.com/random.php');
```

is changed to:

```
$('#divToRefresh').load('random.php');
```

and placed in the same folder as the html file all is well.

The code for the php file is:

```
<?php
$random1 = sprintf("%02f", rand(0,9212));
echo $random1;
?>
```

What would the revised code that would allow cross domain ajax calls look like? I was reading documentation that talked about a json request wrapper, but I did not get where it was going. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you are not able to use ajax cross domain its not possible, you have the following options though:

1.do the ajax to your own page and make a curl call to that page..

2.do $.getJSON('ur', variables, function(data){}).

there are few other solution, but those 2 are basically your best options

here is how getJson works:

On your server you should have a page that is ready to receive the $_GET sort of like an API or normal ajax call would do with $_POST.

should look something like :

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['jsoncallback']) && !empty($_GET['variable'])){

    /* do whatever you like  with the variable you get as get
    *
    *
    *
    **/

    // echo the name of the callback function + the variables you want to receive back in JS
    echo $_GET['jsoncallback'].'('.json_encode($jason_echo).')';
}
?>
```

Your JS or page you are going to do the call from should look something like:

```
$.getJSON("SomePage/PagethatTakesTheGet.php?jsoncallback=?", {variable:15}, function(response){
    // do whatever you want with response.
});
```

Comment: Could you provide an example using my code as a starting point using jetJSON. I would appreciate it.

Comment: well, with getjson you'll need to create a page on your "server" or whatever cross domain address you need to access, that accepts get call, and retrun a function..  will give you an example soon.

Comment: Alright fixed my answer for you.. dont forget that the call back must be the wrapper of your returned variable from php.